# How to use @if{} blocks with razor to build the equivalent of the following ? : inline code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How could I use @if blocks to build the equivalent of this ? : inline code?  Thx!

```
grid.Column("Name", "Name", format:  @<text>
 <div 
      style='color:  @(@item.Name == "Bill") ? "black" : "red") '                   
  >    
   @item.Name
  </div>
</text>),
```

Comment: Other than doing something like this:

        @if(@item.Name == "Bill")
        {
            <div 
            style='color:  red'                   
             > @item.Name</div>
        }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about externalizing this logic into a partial to avoid the mess:

```
grid.Column("Name", "Name", format:  @Html.Partial("_item", item))
```

and then inside your `_item.cshtml` partial do whatever ifs you want or even better use HTML helper:

```
@model ItemViewModel
<div style="@Html.StyleForItem(item)">
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)
</div>
```